# Macbook Air m2 launch.log continuously growing size

Tags: macos, console

In the Console app I found this file "launch.log" (/private/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd), which is continually increasing in size.

Is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the point of a log file, that it grows as items are added to it.

You will also note that this file (and others) participate in log rotation.  Here is an example.

```
$ ls -lh /private/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd
total 43032
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   6.7M Mar 16 07:13 launchd.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7.0M Mar 16 03:48 launchd.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   7.0M Mar 16 00:01 launchd.log.2
$
```

You can see as the file reaches a particular size, another one is created.  The last few will be retained.